# Git push/pull - Restrict by subdomain

Tags: git

Suppose I start with a git master repository server.

Call it `git.prod.example.com`.

I would like the developers working in `dev.example.com` to be able to `push` to this master server.

However, hosts in `test.example.com`, `training.example.com`, or `prod.example.com`, may only execute `pull` requests.

That is, they can get the code from the master repository, but they can not **change** the code in the master repository.

Can I do that? If so, how?

Everyone would have to have accounts on `git.prod.example.com`, right?

(Or in that subdomain, at least.)

Is git bright enough to analyze the source locations of `push` and `pull` requests, and reject code modifications from what amounts to a subdomain-based black list?

If this is well documented somewhere, a link pointer would be great. My google-fu has failed me, so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to work out the details, but this is probably the closest I'll get to a solution that handles my access control needs:

The developers have `push` access to `git.dev.example.com` *only*, with the repository `init`s including `--shared=group`. Make the developers part of the appropriate group in DEV only.

Then, in `hooks/post-update` include a command that allows the `git` user *only* on `git.dev.example.com` to `push` to `git.prod.example.com`. The PROD server is then made readable from all environments, but no one aside from the `git` user has the ability to update the code there.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do that? If so, how?

- You can use git hooks for such a thing.
  GIt hook can "capture" any request made on the server and then you can block it.

  Simply return exit code 0 or 1 in order to allow or to block commit.
  Check in the hook for the repository name and then decide if to allow or to block it.
- [Here](http://dev.ghost.org/prevent-master-push/) is an example on how to do it.

> Everyone would have to have accounts on git.prod.example.com, right?

- Set this repository as public one (http) so anybody will be able to clone it.

> Is git bright enough to analyze the source locations of `push` and `pull` requests, and reject code modifications from what amounts to a subdomain-based black list?

- Its not a black list. You write your own script to check what you need to do.

---

If you are using central server like bitbucket/github etc some of them have this feature build in. it will vary from server to server nut all of then can do a user management to force permissions.

---

Sample code taken from the attached link:

#!/bin/bash

```
protected_branch='master'  
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

if [ $protected_branch = $current_branch ]  
then  
    read -p "You're about to push master, is that what you intended?   [y|n] " -n 1 -r < /dev/tty
    echo
        if echo $REPLY | grep -E '^[Yy]$' > /dev/null
        then
            exit 0 # push will execute
        fi
    exit 1 # push will not execute
else  
    exit 0 # push will execute
fi
```

Comment: That would work if I could figure out how, or if, git can pass any information about the SSL or HTTP connection into the `.git/hooks` script. `if [ $SOURCE_DOMAIN == "test.example.com" ]; then exit 1; fi` would be really easy. I just haven't found how to pass `$SOURCE_DOMAIN` into a hook script.

Comment: I might be able to do something with the `$SSH_CLIENT` or `$SSH_CONNECTION` environment variables to refuse pushes from selected subnets. I'll see if I can experiment with that. What about http transfers, though? I can refuse `POST` requests from selected subnets, provided I know that the push is coming via a `POST` request from a specified client.

Comment: You can't do it directly, since git doesn't have information about the repository. What you can do it in your git hook to find the folder `$PWD` of your repository and to figure out from there